# Fillna by Gruopby pandas Dataframe from values in other columns and select the most common value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mode, fillna

I have a dataframe with several categorical columns, some of which are missing data. I want to impute these data with similar data that also depends on other values in other columns, using the mode function, taking the first one in case of having several values with the same repetition frequency.

```
ciudad_df = pd.DataFrame({'marca' : ['mazda', 'renault', 'ford', 'mazda', 'mazda', 'mazda', 'mazda'], 
                  'linea' : ['CX5', 'Clio', '150', 'Allegro', '323', 'CX5', 'CX5'],
                  'combustible' : ['gasolina','diesel','gasolina','gasolina', 'gas', 'gas', Nan]})
```

I want to impute the last value, knowing that a Mazda-CX5 can use 'gasolina' or 'gas'. So it should choose either one in case they have the same number of repetitions. I have it this way, but it doesn't do anything:

```
ciudad_df['combustible'] = ciudad_df[['combustible']].fillna(
    ciudad_df.groupby(['marca', 'linea'])['combustible'].apply(pd.Series.mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `ciudad_df.groupby(['marca', 'linea'])['combustible'].apply(pd.Series.mode)` gives you back a MultiIndex'ed mapping from *marca* and *linea* to the mode of *combustible*, but the underlying data isn't indexed at all, so doesn't know what to look for in your new series.

This may not be the most straightforward solution, but it works for me. Just have a function that gives you back a whole dataframe with missing values filled and apply it to the groupby object directly:

```
def fill_mode(df): 
    df['combustible'] = df['combustible'].fillna(df['combustible'].mode()[0])
    return df

df = ciudad_df.groupby(['marca', 'linea']).apply(fill_mode)

#~       marca    linea combustible
#~  0    mazda      CX5    gasolina
#~  1  renault     Clio      diesel
#~  2     ford      150    gasolina
#~  3    mazda  Allegro    gasolina
#~  4    mazda      323         gas
#~  5    mazda      CX5         gas
#~  6    mazda      CX5         gas
```

Comment: It worked by filling in the missing data, but created others where there were none before.